# Cannot run `run-example.cmd`?

Tags: apache-spark

I downloaded the Spark from the official site and run the example app. But I got the following error?

```
PS C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7> .\bin\run-example.cmd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource.
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkArgument(CommandBuilderUtils.java:241)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitArgs(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:160)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:276)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:151)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

Running in `CMD`.

```
C:\spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7>bin\run-example.cmd
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource.
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.CommandBuilderUtils.checkArgument(CommandBuilderUtils.java:241)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitArgs(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:160)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildSparkSubmitCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:276)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.buildCommand(SparkSubmitCommandBuilder.java:151)
        at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

Comment: Try from normal command window, `cmd`, not from PowerShell

Comment: Just tried and it got the same error.